# Avoiding DeprecationWarning when extracting indices to subset vectors

Tags: python, numpy, subset

General idea: I want to take a slice of a 3D surface plot of a function of two variables `f(x,y)` at a given `x = some value`. The problem is that I have to know the index where `x` assumes this value after creating `x` as a vector with `np.linspace`, for instance. Finding this index turns out to be doable thanks to another post in SO. What I can't do is use this index as is returned to subset a different vector `Z`, because of the index is returned as a 1-element list (or tuple), and I need an integer. When I use `int()` I get a warning:

```
import numpy as np

lim = 10
x = np.linspace(-lim,lim,2000)
y = np.linspace(-lim,lim,2000)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = X**2 + Y**2

def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]

idx = int(np.where(x == find_nearest(x,0))[0])
print(idx)
print(Z[idx,:].shape)
```

Output with warning:

```
<ipython-input-282-c2403341abda>:16: DeprecationWarning: Conversion of an array with ndim > 0 to a scalar is deprecated, and will error in future. Ensure you extract a single element from your array before performing this operation. (Deprecated NumPy 1.25.)
  idx = int(np.where(x == find_nearest(x,0))[0])
1000
(2000,)
```

The shape of the ultimate sub-setting of `Z` is `(2000,)`, which allows me to plot it against `x`.

However, if instead I just extract with `[0]` the value return by `np.where()`, the shape of the final sub-set `Z`, i.e. `(1,2000)` is not going to allow me to plot it against `x`:

```
idx1 = np.where(x == find_nearest(x,0))[0]
print(idx1)
print(Z[idx1,:].shape)
```

How can I extract the index corresponding to the value of `x` is want as an integer, and thus avoid the warning (see below)?

`DeprecationWarning: Conversion of an array with ndim > 0 to a scalar is deprecated, and will error in future. Ensure you extract a single element from your array before performing this operation. (Deprecated NumPy 1.25.) idx = int(np.where(x == find_nearest(x,0))[0])`

Comment: `np.where(x == find_nearest(x,0))[0][0]`

Comment: `where` gives a tuple of arrays.  The first `[0]` selects the first array.  But that array may have 0, 1, or more elements.  `item()` gives a scalar if there is only 1 element. `[0]` gives the first, but an eror if none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break down the resulting value you get from `np.where`:

```py
>>> np.where(x == find_nearest(x,0))
(array([1000]),)
```

Then dereference the first element:

```py
>>> np.where(x == find_nearest(x,0))[0]
array([1000])
```

Ok, same thing. Get first element:

```py
>>> np.where(x == find_nearest(x,0))[0][0]
1000
```